# App crashing when trying to add a second table

Tags: java, android

Ok so I'm really confused at the moment.  I'm trying to add a new table to my program, but whenever I do I crashes on my, specifically at the onCreate method.  I cannot for the love of me figure out why.  Any suggestions?

Also this is an error I get, but I can't find categories.db anywhere

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: categories.db (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM categories.db

```
private final static int DB_VERSION = 2;

public static String TABLE_NAME = "players";
public static String DB_NAME = "playerslist.db";
public static String SCORE = "score";
public static String ID = "_id";
public static String PLAYER_NAME = "name";

public static String CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME = "categories";
public static String CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
public static String CATEGORY_VALUE = "category_value";
public static String CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
public static String CATEGORY_PLAYER_ID = "category_player_id";

public static String CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+PLAYER_NAME+" TEXT, "+
        SCORE+" TEXT)";
public static String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME+"("+CATEGORY_ID+" INTEGER" +
        "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CATEGORY_NAME+" TEXT, "+CATEGORY_VALUE+" INTEGER, "
        +CATEGORY_PLAYER_ID+" INTEGER)";

public SQLHelp(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    for(int i = oldVersion; i < newVersion; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 1:
                db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the call stack with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

While creating the second table, you had "INTEGER" + "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"..

I made that in one.

```
public static String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME+"("+CATEGORY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CATEGORY_NAME+" TEXT, "+CATEGORY_VALUE+" INTEGER, "
    +CATEGORY_PLAYER_ID+" INTEGER)";
```

You should call SQLiteOpenHelper

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
          db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
          db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2{
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
          onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: That was it, the separation was from the editor when I put it another line to make it more readable.  But there was no space between the integer and primary.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CREATE TABLE Strings to include `IF NOT EXISTS` as,
 `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_name(Columns)`

Comment: I see how that would be useful if I'm just reinstalling it, but I'm completely deleting the data from the settings menu and then unistalling it, so there shouldn't be a database related to my app when I install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your application from the device or emulator, and INSTALL/RUN again, and it should work.

I had the same problem, and I simple delete the application from device and it worked.

Comment: I tried that, I cleared the data from from settings and then uninstalled it, but it still won't run and crashes on the second table being made.